# Comparing two images using ImageComparer of Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests, ui-testing

I need to compare two images using ImageComparer.Compare(currentImage, savedImage, tol, out imageDiff);

i implemented the code in the following manner but always get false as the result . Please help where I am going wrong.

```
private static Image CompareImages(Image savedImage, Image currentImage, string referenceImagesFolder)
        {
            const int borderWidth = 4;
            var rectangle1 = new Rectangle(new Point(borderWidth, borderWidth),
                new Size(savedImage.Width - borderWidth * 2, savedImage.Height - borderWidth * 2));
            var rectangle = rectangle1;
            var tol = new List<ToleranceRectangle>
            {
                new ToleranceRectangle()
                {
                    Rectangle = rectangle,
                    Difference = new ColorDifference()
                }
            };
            Image imageDiff;

            var compareResult = ImageComparer.Compare(currentImage, savedImage, tol, out imageDiff);
            if (!compareResult)
            {
               return imageDiff;
            }
            return null;
```

Comment: Did you examine the output `imageDiff`, it might show you what went wrong.  Also, did you validate all input params?  Is the `rectangle1` what you expect it to be?  If this is part of a test, you should verify these assumptions using whatever `TestTools.UITesting` gives you.

Comment: Imagediff is giving an image that is totally black with very few string visible (it might be the difference in the two images) But I need to know how can I set my tolerance rectangle so that My imagecomapare function returns true despite of little (say delta) difference in resolution.

Comment: Difference in resolution between the two images?  I am **totally guessing** that `ImageComparer` doesn't support that.  It is pixel-by-pixel (judging from the MSDN docs).  You might want to scale the captured test image to match the same resolution as the saved image, then use ImageComparer with some pixel tolerance that makes it reliable.  But that's the many joys of UI Testing, you'll have to tweak this pixel tolerance until you have something that correctly detects failures and has little or no false positives.  Instead, you might want to store saved images for each resolution to be checked